# how to get index by name from multi index container formed with indices using type hiding

Tags: boost, boost-multi-index

I am trying to make multiple index container using type hiding for indexed_by part.
So i start by making the type to be used in container and make some tags

```
struct Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct   //Duration_Signal_Folder_Map_struct >>>log file destination
{

    int         Id;
    std::string Duration;
    std::string FolderDuration;
    std::string FolderDurationSpecefied;
    std::string FolderDurationPathString;
    std::string FolderDurationSpecefiedPathString;


    Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct(const std::string& duration, const std::string& folderdurationspecefied, std::string const& folderdurationspecefiedpathstring ) : Duration(duration), FolderDurationSpecefied(folderdurationspecefied), FolderDurationSpecefiedPathString(folderdurationspecefiedpathstring)
    {
        if (duration == "AllTime")
        {
            Id = 0;
        }
        else if (duration == "Yearly")
        {
            Id = 1;
        }
        else if (duration == "Monthly")
        {
            Id = 2;
        }
        else if (duration == "Daily")
        {
            Id = 3;
        }
        /*
        switch (duration)
        {
        case "AllTime": printf("Choice is AllTime");
            break;
        case "Yearly": printf("Choice is 2");
            break;
        case "Monthly": printf("Choice is 3");
            break;
        case "Daily": printf("Choice is 3");
            break;
        default: printf("Choice other than 1, 2 and 3");
            break;
        }
        */
    }

    bool operator<(const Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct& e)const { return Id<e.Id; }
};
/* tags for accessing the corresponding indices of Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct_set */

struct Id {};
struct Duration_d {};
struct FolderDuration {};
struct FolderDurationSpecefied {};
/*
struct FolderDurationPathString {};
struct FolderDurationSpecefiedPathString {};

struct Duration_FolderDuration {};
struct FolderDuration_FolderDurationSpecefied {};
struct FolderDurationSpecefiedPathString {};
struct FolderDurationSpecefiedPathString {};
struct FolderDurationSpecefiedPathString {};
*/
struct D_FD_FDS {};
/*
*NB: The use of derivation here instead of simple typedef is explained in
* Compiler specifics : type hiding.
*/

struct D_FD_FDS_key :composite_key <
    Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct,
    BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct, std::string, Duration),
    BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct, std::string, FolderDuration),
    BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct, std::string, FolderDurationSpecefied)
> {};




struct Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct_set_indices :
    indexed_by <
    ordered_unique<
    //tag<Id>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct, int, Id)>,
    tag<Id>, member<Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct, int, &Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct::Id> >,
    ordered_non_unique<
    tag<Duration_d>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct, std::string, Duration)>,
    ordered_non_unique<
    tag<FolderDuration>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct, std::string, FolderDuration)>,
    ordered_non_unique<
    tag<FolderDurationSpecefied>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct, std::string, FolderDurationSpecefied)>,
    ordered_unique<
    tag<D_FD_FDS>, D_FD_FDS_key >
    >
{};
typedef multi_index_container<
    Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct,
    Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct_set_indices
> Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct_set;
```

Then i make typedef for one index of this container

```
typedef Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct_set::index<D_FD_FDS>::type Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct_set_by_D_FD_FDS;
```

but when i try to use `Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct_set_by_D_FD_FDS` to get iterator ,intellisense of visual studio tells me that the type of this index is `mpl::void`

i think this is related to type hiding as now the multi index typedef does not have the expanded indexed_by list..
how can i retrieve certain index from multiindex container typedefined with derived struct of indexed_by???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your code. For instance, the following works perfectly (complete sample [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mrrq2omjQ8m9tPfJ)):

```
typedef Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct_set::index<D_FD_FDS>::type Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct_set_by_D_FD_FDS;
typedef Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct_set_by_D_FD_FDS::iterator  Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct_set_by_D_FD_FDS_iterator;    

int main() 
{
  Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct_set                      s;
  Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct_set_by_D_FD_FDS&         sd=s.get<D_FD_FDS>();
  Log_file_Dur_Sig_F_Map_struct_set_by_D_FD_FDS_iterator first=sd.begin(),last=sd.end();
  assert(first==last);
}
```

So, my guess is that Intellisense is choking due to the complexity of the types involved. This shouln't in principle prevent you from going on with compilation.

Comment: Internal meta programming stuff. The library user shouldn't be even aware of it.

Comment: i tested the code and it works fine....but intellisense is not working properly and always says that there is no methods find replace ....as members of boost::mpl::void_...intellisense is helpful reminding me of required arguments and available functions and methods....do you have any idea to fix it regarding this mpl::void_class???

Comment: I'm no Intellisense expert, sorry.